# For loop equation into Octave / Matlab code

Tags: matlab, function, for-loop, octave

I'm using octave 3.8.1 which works like matlab.

I have an array of thousands of values I've only included three groupings as an example below:

*(amp1=0.2; freq1=3; phase1=1; is an example of one grouping)*

```
t=0;
amp1=0.2; freq1=3; phase1=1;   %1st grouping
amp2=1.4; freq2=2; phase2=1.7; %2nd grouping
amp3=0.8; freq3=5; phase3=1.5; %3rd grouping
```

The *Octave* / *Matlab* code below solves for *Y* so I can plug it back into the equation to check values along with calculating values not located in the array.

```
clear all
t=0;
Y=0;
a1=[.2,3,1;1.4,2,1.7;.8,5,1.5]
for kk=1:1:length(a1)
    Y=Y+a1(kk,1)*cos ((a1(kk,2))*t+a1(kk,3))
    kk
end
Y
```

**PS: I'm not trying to solve for Y since it's already solved for I'm trying to solve for Phase**

**The formulas located below are used to calculate *Phase* but I'm not sure how to put it into a for loop that will work in an array of** ***n groupings***:

**How would I write the equation / for loop for finding the phase if I want to find freq=2.5 and amp=.23 and the phase is unknown**  I've looked online and it may require writing non linear equations which I'm not sure how to convert what I'm trying to do into such an equation.

```
phase1_test=acos(Y/amp1-amp3*cos(2*freq3*pi*t+phase3)/amp1-amp2*cos(2*freq2*pi*t+phase2)/amp1)-2*freq1*pi*t
phase2_test=acos(Y/amp2-amp3*cos(2*freq3*pi*t+phase3)/amp2-amp1*cos(2*freq1*pi*t+phase1)/amp2)-2*freq2*pi*t
phase3_test=acos(Y/amp3-amp2*cos(2*freq2*pi*t+phase2)/amp3-amp1*cos(2*freq1*pi*t+phase1)/amp3)-2*freq2*pi*t
```

Image of formula below:
[image: image of formula]

I would like to do a check / calculate phases if given a *freq* and *amp* values.

I know I have to do a for loop but how do I convert the *phase* equation into a for loop so it will work on **n groupings** in an array ***and calculate different values not found in the array***?

Basically I would be given an array of **n groupings** and *freq=2.5* and *amp=.23* and use the formula to calculate *phase*.  Note: freq will not always be in the array hence why I'm trying to calculate the *phase* using a formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think I finally understand your question:

- you are trying to find a set of `phase1`, `phase2`,..., `phaseN`, such that equations like the ones you describe are satisfied
- You know how to find `y`, and you supply values for `freq` and `amp`.
- In Matlab, such a problem would be solved using, for example `fsolve`, but let's look at your problem step by step.

For simplicity, let me re-write your equations for `phase1`, `phase2`, and `phase3`. For example, your first equation, the one for `phase1`, would read

`amp1*cos(phase1 + 2 freq1 pi t) + amp2*cos(2 freq2 pi t + phase2) + amp3*cos(2 freq3 pi t + phase3) - y = 0`

Note that `ampX` (`X` is a placeholder for `1`, `2`, `3`) are given, `pi` is a constant, `t` is given via `Y` (I think), `freqX` are given.

Hence, you are, in fact, dealing with a non-linear vector equation of the form

`F(phase) = 0`

where `F` is a multi-dimensional (vector) function taking a multi-dimensional (vector) input variable `phase` (comprised of `phase1`, `phase2`,..., `phaseN`). And you are looking for the set of phaseX, where *all* of the components of your vector function `F` are zero. N.B. `F` is a shorthand for your functions. Therefore, the first component of `F`, called `f1`, for example, is

`f1 = amp1*cos(phase1+...) + amp2*cos(phase2+...) + amp3*cos(phase3+...) - y = 0`.

Hence, `f1` is a one-dimensional function of `phase1`, `phase2`, and `phase3`.

The technical term for what you are trying to do is *find a zero of a non-linear vector function*, or *find a solution of a non-linear vector function*. In Matlab, there are different approaches.

For a one-dimensional function, you can use `fzero`, which is explained at http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fzero.html?refresh=true

For a multi-dimensional (vector) function as yours, I would look into using `fsolve`, which is part of Matlab's optimization toolbox (which means I don't know how to do this in Octave). The function `fsolve` is explained at http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fsolve.html

If you know an approximate solution for your phases, you may also look into iterative, local methods.

In particular, I would recommend you look into the *Newton's Method*, which allows you to find a solution to your system of equations `F`. Wikipedia has a good explanation of Newton's Method at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method . Newton iterations are very simple to implement and you should find a lot of resources online. You will have to compute the derivative of your function `F` with respect to each of your variables `phaseX`, which is very simple to compute since you're only dealing with `cos()` functions. For starters, have a look at the one-dimensional Newton iteration method in Matlab at http://www.math.colostate.edu/~gerhard/classes/331/lab/newton.html .

Finally, if you want to dig deeper, I found a textbook on this topic from the society for industrial and applied math: https://www.siam.org/books/textbooks/fr16_book.pdf .

As you can see, this is a very large field; Newton's method should be able to help you out, though.

Good luck!